# Adding twice in hash table in C

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

Based on print statements in the rehashing section, I can see that the same string is getting added to the table multiple times. I believe the problem is in this function, although I can't see where. The print statement below return is never executed, so I know that the function actually executes.

Any ideas on where the problem is, or how I should go about finding it? Thanks. The full code on our repository is here:

https://github.com/csking1/buddhism/blob/master/Finding/hash_tables.c

```
void add_to_table(HashTable *h, char* str, LinkedList* new){
  unsigned int hashval = hash(h, str);
  LinkedList *list;

  // walk through the table and check for the first free spot, start at hash val and go to the top
  for (int i = hashval; i<h->size; i++){
    list = h->table[i];
    if (list == NULL){
        new->next = h->table[i];
        h->table[i] = new;
        new->string = str;
        return;
        printf("%s\n", "didn't return");
    }
  }
  // start at the bottom of the table, check for the first free spot up to hash val, then return
  for (int i = 0; i < hashval; i++){
    list = h->table[i];
    if (list == NULL){
        new->next = h->table[i];
        h->table[i] = new;
        new->string = str;
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

For a full view, here's the string lookup function. This gets called one or two lines above the add_to_table() function, and returns if the string is already there.

```
LinkedList *lookup_string(HashTable *h, char *str){
  LinkedList *list;
  unsigned int hashval = hash(h, str);

  for (int i = hashval; i < h->size; i++){
    list = h->table[i];
    if (list == NULL){
      return NULL;
    }
    if (list != NULL){
      if (strcmp(str, list->string) == 0){
        return list;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < hashval; i++){
    list = h->table[i];
    if (list == NULL){
      return NULL;
    }
    if (list != NULL){
      if (strcmp(str, list->string) == 0){
        return list;
      }
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Well. This line is probably wrong: `new->string = str;`. This is not how you copy strings. Unless youa re always allocating a new string before passing to the function.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh., I just changed it to `new->string = strdup(str)`, and changed it in my makefile to -std=gnu99, because apparently c99 doesn't support that function. Unfortunately it still doesn't solve the problem, or at least not this one.

Comment: Where do you check that the string is not already in the hash table? (Check `man strdup` for the Feature Test Macro requirements to enable `strdup`. tl;dr: put `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`  at the very top of your source file, before any `#include` directive.)

Comment: Thanks @rici, I just added the other function.

Comment: Don't you find it odd that the lookup function never follows the linked list? What's the point of linking nodes if you don't use the links?

Comment: Oh dear, it seems I was adding to the wrong hash table in the function call.

Comment: @rici: I'm still new to C, and I see that this format doesn't really use the functionality of linked lists. I am mostly just using them to store other values. I see that this is a problem, and maybe at some point I'll be able to come back and address it. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! I think you are confusing two completely different types of hash tables: open-addressing and separate-chaining. The [Wikipedia article on Hash Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) has a pretty good discussion with sample pseudo-code.